# Is there an easy way to tell how much time is spent waiting for the Python GIL?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a long-running Python service and I'd like to know how much cumulative wall clock time has been spent by any runnable threads (i.e., threads that weren't blocked for some other reason) waiting for the GIL.  Is there an easy way to do this?  E.g., perhaps I could periodically dump some counter to its log file.

My underlying motivation is to rule out the GIL as a source of mystery response latency from these long-running processes.  There is no particular reason to suspect the GIL (other than that it would fit the symptoms), but other forms of logging haven't turned up anything yet, so, *if it is easy*, it would be nice to have this information.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's an easy way. There's probably an awkward way, involving rebuilding Python to traverse the PyThreadState list and count the threads each time the lock is acquired, but I doubt it's worth the effort!

I know this is a speculative question but if you are even moderately concerned about there being delays caused by threading it may be prudent to move to a multiprocessing model instead of a multithreading model. Since processes are both safer and more scalable in Python they are almost always the best choice if practical.

Answer (score 2):

You can now profile GIL usage using [gil_load](https://github.com/chrisjbillington/gil_load).

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42818585/2096752) to the to that other question.

Comment: The gil_load project tells you how often the GIL is held (that is, *at least one* thread is runnable). The question asks how often the GIL is being waited upon (that is, *at least two* threads are runnable). How do you achieve that with gil_load?

Comment: As of version 0.4, gil_load can now tell you what proportion of time threads are waiting for the GIL, on a per-thread basis.

Answer (score 0):

I find pyspy to be useful for finding out how much and where Python spends time holding the GIL. You can run your program, look up the PID in htop, and then run:

```
py-spy record --gil --pid 2240761
```

After a minute, you can <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> and it will write an interactive SVG file out that shows the flame graph of what fraction of the time which function held the GIL (you can click to zoom into sections):

[image: pyspy gil flame graph]